# Return name of object and the key based on the value from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

```
        {
      ALBVM1: {
        'C:\\ Drive Space': 2,
        'CPU Load': 2,
        'Hyper-V Replica Health': 2,
        'Hyper-V VM Health': 2,
        'MSRPC - 135': 2,
        'Memory Usage': 2,
        'RDP - 3389': 2,
        Uptime: 2,
        'V:\\ Drive Space': 2,
        'Windows Services': 2
      },
      ALBVM2: {
        'C:\\ Drive Space': 2,
        'CPU Load': 2,
        'Hyper-V Replica Health': 2,
        'Hyper-V VM Health': 2,
        'MSRPC - 135': 2,
        'Memory Usage': 16,
        'RDP - 3389': 2,
        Uptime: 2,
        'V:\\ Drive Space': 2,
        'Windows Services': 2
      }
}
```

> If the value is **16** i want to get the values to return 'Memory Usage' and ALBVM2
>   Is it possible to write a function to get the above vaues

Comment: What have you tried and what is your current issue?

Comment: I would recommend you read up on accessing properties in JavaScript objects, and how to parse JSON text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your values like this:

```
let result = null
for (const entry in JSON_DATA) {
    console.log(entry, JSON_DATA[entry])
    let entries = Object.entries(JSON_DATA[entry])

    entries.forEach(([entry_key, entry_val]) => {
        if (entry_val === 16) { // replace the 16 with any other variable you wish to search for
            result = [entry_key, JSON_DATA[entry]] // will return 'Memory Usage' and the Object that contains the key value pair, you can replace `JSON_DATA[entry]` with entry if you just want the name of the object
            return
        }
    })
}
console.log(result)
```

You can wrap this in a function and change the string value you're looking for to get other key value pairs.

More on these methods:

- [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [For..in Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)